# WPF How do I allow my ControlTemplate to use an existing NavigationService?

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, navigationservice, navigationwindow

I have a `ControlTemplate` for a Menu which I want to be used for all my Pages. The function calls of the `ControlTemplate` requires the usage of the `NavigationService` belonging my `NavigationWindow`. However, I can not place the `ControlTemplate` in the `NavigationWindow xaml` file, because it is not accessible to the Pages. How would I allow my `ControlTemplate` to access the `NavigationService` while being available to use in my Pages?

My `NavigationWindow` is located at `MainWindow.xaml`

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
namespace WPFApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void Menu_ModeAdvanced_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Where I want to access the Navigation Service
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application x:Class="WPFApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApplication"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- Page Design -->
            <Style TargetType="Page">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FBF5F3" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#363537" />
            </Style>
            
            <!-- Label Design-->
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FBF5F3" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <!-- Menu Template-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="StandardMenu" TargetType="Menu">
            <Menu Height="20">
                <MenuItem Header="File" AllowDrop="True">
                    <MenuItem Header="Mode" AllowDrop="True">
                        <MenuItem Header="Advanced"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have tried putting the `ControlTemplate` and related code into a `ResourceDictionary` located in the `NavigationWindow`'s class. However, I could not use it as a static resource in my pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the parent `Window` of the `MenuItem`. If it is the `NavigationWindow` you can use its API to execute navigation related tasks or use its associated `NavigationWindow.NavigationService`:

```cs
private void Menu_ModeAdvanced_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FrameworkElement element = sender as FramwworkElement;
  NavigationWindow navigationWindow = null;
  while (element.Parent is not null)
  {
    element = element.Parent as FrameworkElement;
    if (element is NavigationWindow window)
    {
      navigationWindow = window;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Navigate etc. using the NavigationWindow API
  navigationWindow?.Navigate(new Uri());
 
  // Navigate etc. using the NavigationService
  navigationWindow?.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri());
}
```

But I recommend defining routed commands in your `NavigationWindow`.
It's much cleaner from a design perspective as the navigation details are kept private to the navigation host:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : NavigationWindow
{
  public static RoutedCommand NavigateToPageCommand { get; }
    = new RoutedCommand(nameof(MainWindow.NavigateToPageCommand, typeof(MainWindow)); 

  private Dictionary<PageId, Uri> PageUriStore { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var navigateCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      MainWindow.NavigateToPageCommand,
      ExecutedNavigateToPageCommand,
      CanexecutedNavigateToPageCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(navigateCommandBinding);

    this.PageUriStore = new Dictionary<PageId, Uri>
    {
      { PageId.SettingsPage, new Uri(...) },
    };
  }

  private void CanexecutedNavigateToPageCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = e.Parameter is PageId;

  private void CanexecutedNavigateToPageCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var pageId = (PageId)e.Parameter;
    if (this.PageUriStore.TryGetValue(pageId, out Uri destinationUri))
    {
      this.Navigate(ddestinationUri);
    }
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<MenuItem Header="Settings"
          Command="{x:Static MainWindow.NavigateToPageCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{x:Static PageId.SettingsPage}" />
```

**PageId.cs**

```cs
enum PageId
{
  Default = 0,
  OverviewPage,
  SettingsPage
}
```